# Python3 ElementTree not behaving as expected

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-model href="../tool/rules/rules.sch" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>

<block name="test_debug" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://my-specific-ns"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../tool/rules/schema.xsd" simul="true">
</block>
```

And my Python3 code is the following

```
XmlRoot = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot() #type: ElementTree
XmlRoot.attrib
```

and I get the following output

```
{'name': 'test_debug', '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': '../tool/rules/schema.xsd', 'simul': 'true'}
```

I do not understand why there are two attributes missing.

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

and

```
xmlns="http://my-specific-ns"
```

I am interested in getting the xmlns attribute. Because its the namespace used by through my XML files and it will make it easier to search for specific paths.

PS I'm using Python 3.7.

/Regards

Comment: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and `xmlns="http://my-specific-ns"` are not "real" attributes. They are namespace declarations and do not populate `attrib`. If you can move to Python 3.8, there is the option of using wildcards for namespaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117710/407651.

Comment: Or use lxml, which has a `nsmap` property on elements: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21569520/407651